# Hahn-Banach Theorem about probability measure

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and define $A(K)$ to be $\{f\in C(K): f \text{ is analytic on int} K\}$. Show that if $a\in K$, then there is a probability measure $\mu$ supported on $\partial K$ such that $f(a)=\int f \, d\mu$ for every $f$ in $A(K)$. (A probability measure is a nonnegative measure $\mu$ such that $\Vert \mu \Vert=1$)

How to apply Hahn-Banach theorem??

Comment: if $f$ was analytic on $K$ (instead of $K \setminus \partial K$) it would be easier. and note that $f \in C(K)$ should mean that $f$ is complex-continuous on $\partial K$ (i.e. $\lim_{ z \to a} f(z) = f(a)$ whenever $z \to a,z\in K$)

Comment: Hint: The Maximum Modulus Theorem shows that $|f(a)|\le\sup_{z\in\partial K}|f(z)|$.

Comment: But.. how to induce $f(a)=\int f d\mu$ for every f in $A(K)$?

Comment: Let $X=\{f|_{\partial K}: f\in A(K)\}$. So $X$ is a subspace of $C(\partial K)$. Define a linear functional $\Lambda$ on $X$ by $\Lambda f=f(a)$ ($f\in A(K)$)...

Comment: Then, by Hahn-Banach Theorem, we can find linear functional $g: C(\partial K) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that g (restriction on X) = $\Lambda$ and $\vert g \vert \leq sup_{z\in \partial K} \vert f(z) \vert$. Also, By Riesz representation theorem, there exists measure $\mu$ such that $g(f)=\int f d\mu$. Right?

Comment: Right. Now you need to show that $\mu$ is a probability measure.

Comment: Can you give some hints about probability meausre?..

Comment: What is the norm of $\mu$? And what is $\int 1\,d\mu$?

Comment: $\Vert \mu \Vert=sup_{\Vert f \Vert \leq 1} \vert \int f d\mu \vert$  Then, $\Vert \mu \Vert \leq 1$ (Cauchy-Schwartz inequality ) But, I don't know $\int 1 d\mu$ value..